# How to use properties in a Spring project to configure log4j.xml

Tags: spring, logging, log4j

I have multiple properties files in my Spring project.  The spring context loads these properties and handles property overriding in a convenient manner.  Is there a way to take the properties that are available to my Spring configuration XML files (ie. `${myprop}`) and use them in a similar fashion in my `log4j.xml` file?  I know that I can pass system properties to log4j using `-Dprop=value` on startup, but I would prefer having all of the configuration in the properties files in my project.  Is this possible?

My app runs in Tomcat.

Comment: I don't think you can do this - log4j doesn't provide this kind of introspection.

Comment: Even if this was possible, you would potentially miss some logging because Spring itself would log to log4j when starting the context and loading the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this class, after integrating your multiple properties files to one Properties.

```
public class DOMConfiguratorWithProperties extends DOMConfigurator {

    private Properties propertiesField = null;

    public synchronized Properties getProperties() {
        return propertiesField;
    }

    public synchronized void setProperties(final Properties properties) {
        propertiesField = properties;
    }

    @Override
    protected String subst(final String value) {
        return super.subst(value, getProperties());
    }

    public static void configure(final String filename) {
        new DOMConfiguratorWithProperties().doConfigure(
                filename,
                LogManager.getLoggerRepository());
    }

    public static void configure(
            final String filename,
            final Properties properties) {
        DOMConfiguratorWithProperties configurator = new DOMConfiguratorWithProperties();
        configurator.setProperties(properties);
        configurator.doConfigure(
                filename,
                LogManager.getLoggerRepository());
    }
}
```

Comment: THis looks like a valid solution.  Unfortunately, because I'm working in a Spring web container, I can't get this code to execute until much of the context has already loaded.  This means that there will be lots of initial logging that won't go to my new log location (defined by my properties file).  I don't like the idea of an app logging to multiple locations, so I think I'll give up on my hope of making the logging the location more flexible through properties files.  Thanks for your answer.  I'm sure someone will benefit from this code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you can interact with Log4J is through the [Nested diagnostic context](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/NDC.html).

So if you are very desperate, you could write a Spring AOP aspect that sets the diagnostic context for your Spring Bean logs (and you could use the properties there). However, that would require that the Log be available to the Spring Bean, so you would need to add a `getLog()` method to your service interfaces (this gets a lot easier if you use static AspectJ compilation and is described in [AspectJ in Action](http://www.manning.com/laddad2/)).

But short of using AOP, I can't think of a sensible way to let Spring and Log4J interact.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.  From what you said, I have a follow question: Is it possible to have a log4j.xml file use an external properties file -so that some of the settings are hard-coded in the xml file?

Comment: How about using resource filtering with maven or ant?