# load log4j.xml configuration parameters from a properties file

Tags: properties, log4j

I have a web application configured with log4j(version 1.2) in the xml configuration. I wanted to ask if it is possible to load the configuration parmaters such as the JDBCAppender url and sql query from a separate properties file.I want the values in Log4j.xml file to come from a separate common properties file
I have seen the [**docs**](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) but i could'nt find anything on including an external file.

If there is a similar question already asked please give me the link to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it wont let me comment, i'll have to post it as an answer.

[How to use properties in a Spring project to configure log4j.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127515/how-to-use-properties-in-a-spring-project-to-configure-log4j-xml?rq=1)

It does not seem to be possible. I need the same thing but it would seem the only solution is to use maven or ant resource filtering but this is only useful if you can rebuild everytime you need to change the properties.

EDIT:

Ok so i found a few possible solutions. While it is not possible to do directly, you can subclass the appender and load the property directly into the subclass.

You could also load the appender programmatically. But then it wont append during startup so not ideal in every situation.

Comment: Your right all the initialization logs won't be appended, and the solution is not ideal in every situation.

Comment: No problem, just happy to help!